# Create line plot from dataframe with two columns index

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, multi-index, line-plot

I have the following dataframe:

```
>>>                          mean_traf_tie
    a      d        c
    0.22  0.99      0.11      22
                    0.23      21
                    0.34      34
                    0.46      45
    0.44  0.99      0.11      45
                    0.23      65
                    0.34      66
                    0.46      68
    0.50  0.50      0.11      22
                    0.23      12
                    0.34      34
                    0.46      37
...
```

I want to crate plot from this dataframe, on a way that c will be the X axis, y will be the mean velocity and lines will be according to the a and d columns, so for example, one line will be for a=0.22 and d=0.99, the x will be c and y will be mean velocity, and then the 2nd line will be for a=0.44 and d=0.99 ect.

I have tried to do it like this:

```
df.plot()
```

[image]

(values are differrent in original dataframe).

as you can see,for some reason it plots i nthe x axis the a,d and creates only one line.

I have tried to fix it like this:

```
df.unstack(level=0).plot(figsize=(10,6))
```

but then I got very weird graph, with the correct lines by a and d but wrong x axis:
[image]

As you can see, it plot somehow the a,d values ,but that not what I want- I want it to be the c columns, and then to create lines based on the a,d columns,which suppose to create continous line.
I have trid that as well:

```
df[('mean_traf_tie')].unstack(level=0).plot(figsize=(10,6))
plt.xlabel('C')
plt.ylabel('mean_traf_tie')
```

but got again:
[image]

The desired output will have the c column as x axis, the mean_traf_tie as y axis, and lines will be generated bseed on a and d columns (line for 0.22 and 0.99, line for 0.44 and 0.99 ect).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:
I Have managed to go over it by concatinating the two index columns to one before plotting like this:

```
df['a,d'] = list(zip(df.a, df.d))

df=df.groupby(['a,d','C']).mean()

df.unstack(level=0).plot(figsize=(10,6))
```

[image]

the legenss is still not idealistic but I got the lines and axes as I wanted.

If anyone has better idea how to do it with original columns, i'm still open to learn.